# Sending objects between activities

Tags: android

There are two activity classes in my project and a third class which is subclass of `Thread`.

`Thread` Class implements `Bluetooth Socket` which isn't `Parcelable`.

`First Activity` starts the `Second Activity` using `startActivityforResult()`

`Second Activity` creates an object of the `Thread` class and starts the thread.

I need to pass an object reference of the Thread object from `Second Activity` to `First Activity's onActivityResult()` so that I can access Thread object from the first activity.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: People should stop thinking in Activities all the time. They are the UI, you can do work *elsewhere*, too.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  Passing data between activities is done using serialisation, so you can have your Thread subclass implement Serializable or Parcelable and pass it back using the return intent.

Comment: You can only pass primitive types (beside Parcelable) between Activities, why don't you start your Thread in your first Activity after the onActivityResult() ?

Comment: @PlumillonForge you can pass complex data objects by having them correctly implement Parcelable interface.

Comment: @PlumillonForge I cannot start the thread in my first activity in activity result coz Thread's constructor need a field of second activity

Comment: Can you pass this field back to your first Activity and start the Thread at this moment ?

Comment: @PlumillonForge I don't if this is a good way to do but I declared that field as Static and started the thread in first activity.That field is of type 'BluetoothDevice[]'

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options.

You can either break down your object into simple data types and put those values as extras on the intent that you pass back with `setResult()`, do do so you'd use `intent.putExtra(key, value)`

Or you can make your data object implement the [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface so that you can add the data object directly to the intent.

the code to do the latter would look something like this

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("resultObject", mObj);
setResult(ACTION_OK, resultIntent);
```

then inside your onActivityResult you can pull it out like this:

```
data.getParcelableExtra("resultObject");
```

For the latter method to work you need to correctly implement parcelable with your data object. The former method does not require this however, since you'll be passing back simple values only. You'd then have to take those simple values and "re-inflate" the data object on the other side.

Comment: The Object which I want to Parcel contains Bluetooth socket which aren't neither parcelable nor Serializable.What else do you think I can do?

Comment: Then you shouldn't be trying to pass it between two activities like that. There is probably a better way to accomplish what you are needing to do. Maybe extend the Application class and have it store your socket, or maybe use a Service that you can bind to from both activities. Or maybe turn the second activity into "another screen" of the first activity, instead of a completely separate one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this would be to use a singleton. You can only store primitives in Shared Preferences and Bundles. Here is a great reference for creating a singleton.

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html